# Proper way to subtract two 64 bit numbers in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, subtraction

I'm using a 32 bit system and have a 64 bit number saved in EDX:EAX. I'm trying to subtract a number saved in ESI:EDI is this correct? I'm pretty sure its not because after 3 iterations the results are incorrect.

```
sub %esi, %edx          #Subtract two 64 bit numbers
sub %edi, %eax
```

Comment: Look up `sbb`. Subtract the low dword first, then subtract the high dword, with the "borrow" (same as a "carry").

Comment: If you have SSE2 (or even just MMX), it can be more efficient to use `psubq xmm0, xmm1`.  But probably only if you have multiple 64-bit operations to do, or the inputs and outputs are already memory.  (Transferring between xmm and integer regs costs more than `sub`/`sbb`, but careful use of xmm regs can reduce integer register pressure.)

Answer (score 9):

You need to make two changes:

1. Subtract the low order 32-bits first, not the high order
2. If the subtraction of the low order 32-bits generated a `borrow` you need to subtract one more from the high order bits.  Fortunately the CPU remembers if there was a borrow (in the `carry flag` CF) and there is an instruction to subtract with borrow, `SBB`

Here's the final code

```
sub %edi, %eax          # Subtract low order 32-bits, borrow reflected in CF
sbb %esi, %edx          # Subtract high order 32-bits, and the borrow if there was one
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering so many of my questions amdn. My peers and I kind of got tossed into the "deep end" of the pool with the problem that this part of code represents. That being said, I'm using Ubuntu Linux 32 - bit system and correct me if I'm wrong but there is no access to sbb on 32 bit? I was going through some documentation and it said only available on X=arch 64 could this be because I'm using AT&T syntax with GNU AS assembler?

Comment: SBB has been available to everyone since 8086. Maybe the assembler is crippled somehow, but I can't possibly imagine why.

Comment: I think I found the reference, what it says is that sbbq (q=quadword, or 64-bits) is only available in 64-bit mode.  You should use sbbl, here's that link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/eoizh/index.html